How to compare acceleration of two cars with different power curves but same peak power?
If we have two engines with same max power, but with different power curve, how to define which car will accelerate faster? Assumptions is both cars have same mass, aero and tyre drag, neglect shifting time,turbo lag etc.. using classical transmission, not continuously variable transmission (CVT)

same ratios in the gears? what about the diff? LSD?

@SolarMike the best ratios that fit to this curve

what is best? top speed? what was your choice about LSD?

the curve with the greatest torque rise will achieve peak power at lower RPM and thereby provide optimum upshift points at lower RPM. This furnishes quicker shifts because the engine does not have to wind all the way out to max RPM before it hits the max power point. Quicker torque rise will hence yield faster acceleration.

in race rpm never fall down below optimum level, always high...

There's no closed form solution, you would typically use a time based simulation with a bit of logic for the gear shifts and a lookup table for power at a given rpm. The great news is that a high school student can do this. Hardest bit is figuring the launch out.
